# Can I enter Romania with an ID card?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, romania, croatian-citizens

My girlfriend and I (we are Croatian citizens) are going to visit Bucharest, Romania and we plan to stay there for 1 week. We will be traveling from Croatia to Budapest, Hungary first and from there we will take a plane to Bucharest.

Can we do this with our ID cards from Croatia? I did some research and we should be able (from what I found). Since this will be our first flight I just wanted to be sure since she and I don't have valid passports (they expired).

Comment: Are you Croatian citizens?

Comment: @phoog yes we are. Forgot to add that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are Croatian citizens then yes, you can do this.  A valid national ID card is sufficient for any EU citizen to enter any other EU country.

This is specified in directive [2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616).  Article 5(1) says:

> Article 5
>
> Right of entry
>
> 1. Without prejudice to the provisions on travel documents applicable to national border controls, Member States shall grant Union citizens leave to enter their territory **with a valid identity card** or passport and shall grant family members who are not nationals of a Member State leave to enter their territory with a valid passport.
>
>    No entry visa or equivalent formality may be imposed on Union citizens.

(emphasis added)

Comment: This is my first time posting here and also traveling with a plane (maybe i'm just concerned over nothing) I just wanted to be sure. Thank you for the help

Comment: @MePo it is better to be safe than sorry.  Welcome to [Travel.SE]!